# Code snippet not get highlight on page navigation (without site refresh) while using run_prettify.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, pretty-print

We are hosting the website using the bunch of html files. In the html files, we are have the various language code snippets.

To highlight the code snippet , we have referred the https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js in our html files head section.

```html
<head>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>

</head>
```

Also our code tag of html files having the prittyprint like below.

```html
<div class="highlight"><pre><code class="prettyprint language-aspx-cs">@using Company.Web.Mvc.UI</code></pre></div>
```

Code snippet were getting highlighted on initially (page loads). But code snippet in the another page not get highlighted on page navigation. it working if we refresh the page. We are not refreshing the site on page navigation.

Actually , while clicking the toc, another page will be navigated without site refresh.

Let me know how to get the code snippet highlight on page navigation without page refresh ?

Thanks in advance.